# HTML Popup Form Without Involving Address

Tags: html, popup

I have some trouble for my html popup window. First, here is my popup form (unfinished).

```
<!--Popup add new request -->
<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="add_form"></a>
<div class="popup">
    Request for : 
    <a class="close" href="#close"></a>
</div>
```

And this is the button for popup trigger

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='#add_form'">AddX</button>
```

What I mean trouble here is I am using address to bring my popup. So when it's already submitted and I press 'Back' button in my browser, the popup form will appear again. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `window.location.replace (url);` instead of `location.href`

Comment: my bad, use window.location.replace (url);

Comment: That worked.. Still speechless.. Thanks anyway! Sorry for that minus that you get :(